# TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, typeerror

When using this code I get an error. 
While as far as I can tell the surface does have all the positional arguments filled.

I create the player from the block class and I pass in the arguments to create the player. (color, width and height)
After creating the player I add it to all_sprites list and use player.rect.x and player.rect.y to position the block on the screen.

In the end I just draw the all_sprites_list to screen.

However when doing this I get this error:

```
TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.width = width

screen_width = 700
screen_height = 500
size = (screen_width, screen_height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Sprites lists
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group

# Create the player
block_width = 30
block_height = 15
player = Block(BLUE, block_width, block_height)
# Set the initial position for the player in the center of the screen
player.rect.x = screen_width/2 - block_width/2
player.rect.y = screen_height/2 - block_height/2
# Add the player to all_sprites_list
all_sprites_list.add(player)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You need to post a complete traceback and edit your code down to the minimum needed to show the problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for your comment. I have decreased the amount of code to what I think is needed to see the problem.

Comment: We still need the full traceback to be sure the problem is with  `all_sprites_list.draw(screen)` and not another `draw` hidden in the pygame code..  It if is, I am puzzled too, since there is indeed a argument being passed.

Answer (score 2):

pygame.sprite.Group is a class, and according to the documents located [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).

```
Group(*sprites) -> Group
```

What you need to do add parentheses where you call pygame.sprite.Group and add all the sprites in that group within the parentheses like this:

```
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group(player,enemy,etc...)
```

At the very least you need to add parentheses after the Group so that the interpreter doesn't treat it as an object, and calls the function properly.